# Allowing user to rollback from db audit trail with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, audit, rollback

I'm starting to use SQLAlchemy for a new project where I was planning to implement an audit trail similar to the one proposed on these questions:

- [Implementing Audit Trail for Objects in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328898/implementing-audit-trail-for-objects-in-c)
- [Audit trails and implementing SOX/HIPAA/etc, best practices for sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315240/audit-trails-and-implementing-sox-hipaa-etc-best-practices-for-sensitive-data)
- [Ideas on database design for capturing audit trails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051449/ideas-on-database-design-for-capturing-audit-trails)
- [What is the best implementation for DB Audit Trail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-db-audit-trail)
- [Is this the best approach to creating an audit trail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711597/is-this-the-best-approach-to-creating-an-audit-trail)
- [Effective strategy for leaving an audit trail/change history for DB applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770/good-strategy-for-leaving-an-audit-trail-change-history-for-db-applications)
- [Data Auditing in NHibernate and SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917/data-auditing-in-nhibernate-and-sqlserver).

As I will have the full history of the "interesting" objects, I was thinking in allowing users to rollback to a given version, giving them the possibility to have unlimited `undo`.

Would this be possible to be done in a clean way with SQLAlchemy?

What would be the *correct* way to expose this feature in the internal API (business logic and ORM)?

I was something along the ways of `user.rollback(ver=42)`.

Comment: See [sqlalchemy-continuum](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-continuum) versioning extension.

Answer (score 8):

Although I haven't used SQLAlchemy specifically, I can give you some general tips that can be easily implemented in any ORM:

- Separate out the versioned item into two tables, say `Document` and `DocumentVersion`. `Document` stores information that will never change between versions, and `DocumentVersion` stores information that does change.
- Give each `DocumentVersion` a "parent" reference. Make a foreign key to the same table, pointing to the previous version of the document.
- Roll back to previous versions by updating a reference from `Document` to the "current" version. Don't delete versions from the bottom of the chain.
- When they make newer versions after rolling back, it will create another branch of versions.

Example, create A, B, C, rollback to B, create D, E:

```
(A)
 |
(B)
 | \
(C) (D)
     |
    (E)
```

Comment: The allowing of branching is cool, but wouldn't it be really really hard to do merging down the road?

Comment: This is not like source control. From the user's perspective, you have totally deleted C. You will never need to merge it in. The only reason it is still around is as an audit trail, or in case you need to manually fish out a deleted item for some reason.